# Getting a business-card after jumping from a sky-scraper

Tags: noragami

I remember seeing either a trailer for it or a part of the first episode.

There was a guy who tried to commit suicide (I think) and jumped off a tall building. As he was falling this guy and I think 2-3 others kinda fly next to him.

The guy offers him his services to save him or something coz I remember him giving the suicidal guy a card.

Sorry if I didn't describe it very well, but that's a that I remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for [**Noragami**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noragami).

[The scene you described is in episode 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uw5P_rYXit4), where a guy tried to commit suicide by jumping off a rooftop.

The only part that doesn't fit your description, is that the guy jumped. He *intended* to jump, but "accidentally" fell instead.